# Is there possible way to hide cursor inter run time in console In Fortran?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

- I have written a specific software, and this running for generate 6 files with the random numbers in different´s ranges.
- But, I want to hide the ***cursor when this is running***.

  •  **`Is there any possible way to do this?`**

### [image]

> **`• Update •`**

**::** **Answer** from **[`@Daniel R Livingston`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5150303/daniel-r-livingston)**

> **• Solve** the **case** with **something minors adaptation on 1st post:  ::**

***"By this First, printing the escape code [`\e[?25l`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55578964/revisions) will hide your cursor.***

***[`\e[?25h`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55578964/revisions) "will re-enable it."***

---

```
write (*,*)char(27)//char(91)//char(63)//char(50)//char(53)//char(108)

! For some reason, by using the 'result = systemqq' 
! May force the screen to "apply" the line above, only 
! After this, that escape gone works in Windows!

result = systemqq('@cls &@%windir%'//char(92)//'system32'//char(92)//'chcp.exe 850 2>nul >nul 1<&2&@color 0a')
write (*,*)char(27)//'[37;41;4m'//char(255)//char(250)//char(255)//'Generating',x,' Random Numbers!',char(27)
           &//'[0m'//char(10)//char(10)

!    Obs.: --------------------------------------------------------------------
!    Turn the cursor back by adding:
!    write (*,*),char(27)//'[?25h'  before end program (latest line) 
!     \e[?25l == char(27)//char(91)//char(63)//char(50)//char(53)//char(108)
```

---

### [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this.

First, printing the escape code `\e[?25l` will hide your cursor. `\e[?25h` will re-enable it.

Second, by calling the [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorinfo):

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleCursorInfo(
  _In_       HANDLE              hConsoleOutput,
  _In_ const CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO *lpConsoleCursorInfo
);
```

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant mouse cursor. Do you mean the terminal `_` cursor?

Comment: Hi @ItWasn'tMe, I rolled back my answer to the original. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!! By now the question and answer make sense :)